# How to find most recent date for a record and <= today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a database of employees, I need each employee's most recent record that is also equal to or less than today.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM WA
INNER JOIN (SELECT
[Employee]
,MAX(Start_Date) as StartDate
FROM WA
GROUP BY [Employee] HAVING MAX(Start_Date) <= GETDATE() ) as WA2 on WA.Employee = WA2.Employee AND WA.Start_Date = WA2.StartDate
```

The table only has one employee in it for now, for testing purposes, but the result is not showing any records because the max start date is in the future (Jan 19). I would like it to show the most recent start date on or before today, which is Dec 15.

Comment: please add a [mre] with create tables and data and also vthe wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `TOP`

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
  e.*,
  WA.*
FROM Employee e
JOIN WA ON WA.Employee = e.Employee AND WA.Start_Date = e.StartDate
WHERE e.Id = PutIDHere
  AND e.Start_Date <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY
  e.StartDate DESC;
```

If you need multiple employees then use a row-numbering approach.

Comment: I suspect a punitive DV   +1